# How to add a 'title' to each point mapped on Google Maps using python pygmaps?

Tags: python, google-maps, pygmaps

I am trying with below code. I am expecting line[2] value should appear in the map.

```
import pygmaps 
import webbrowser 
import csv
inp = open("storefile.csv", 'rt')
reader = csv.reader(inp)
mymap = pygmaps.maps(37.429, -122.145, 8) 
for line in reader:
   lat = float(line[0])
   long = float(line[1])
   if line[2] == 'user':  
      mymap.addpoint(lat, long, "#0000FF", line[2])
   else:
      mymap.addradpoint(lat, long, 30000, "#FF0000")
      mymap.addpoint(lat, long, "#FF0000")
inp.close() 
mymap.draw('mymap.draw.html') 
url = 'mymap.draw.html'
webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
```

input file contains below records:

```
41.478155,-72.812004,store
41.378155,-72.872004,user
41.578155,-72.752004,user
41.438155,-72.912004,user
```

Everything is getting displayed on map except line[2] value at each point on the map.
Say 'User' or 'store'. Please help in fixing this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with pygmaps.py program I downloaded. In the supplied package there is no option to add a 4th column (title).

Now I modified pygmaps.py program like below:

from

```
def addpoint(self, lat, lng, color = '#FF0000'):
    self.points.append((lat,lng,color[1:]))
```

to:

```
def addpoint(self, lat, lng, color = '#FF0000', title = None):
    self.points.append((lat,lng,color[1:],title))
```

With the modified code I am able to add title the points.